# Eclipse CDT with llvm's libc++ compilation err under ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, llvm-clang, libc++

I can compile and run c++ example in command line like this:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ Test.cpp
```

But when trying this in eclipse,I got these errors

```
12:58:18 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project C++Test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build

clang++ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/ -o
C++Test src/C++Test.bc -llibc++ -lstdc++ 

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibc++

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There are two strange things here:

First,I have actually appended "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" to compile command in project build settings,but it seems be ignored.Why?

Second,I have remove stdc++ from link libraries,but it will be added automatically each time,like this:

**Update:add a picture to demo this problem**
[image: stdc++ will be added automatically again after deleting]

Then,I tried to remove libc++ from link libraries in project settings,compile it again,got 
bunch of errors like these:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
clang++ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/ -o C++Test src/C++Test.bc -lstdc++ 
/tmp/C++Test-d24e4c.o: In function `main':
/home/alex/workspace/C++Test/Debug/../src/C++Test.cpp:12: undefined reference to `std::__1::cout'
/tmp/C++Test-d24e4c.o: In function `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:974: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)'
/tmp/C++Test-d24e4c.o: In function `std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::fill() const':
/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:734: undefined reference to `std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const'
......
```

"-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" ignored still,so how to get it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foremost problem is why the linker cannot find `libc++`:

If you want to link a dynamic library, say, `libfoo.so`, with the `-l` flag,
you use the option `-lfoo`, not `-llibfoo`. Therefore to link `libc++`
you use the option `-lc++`, not `-llibc++`, as you have done. In your
project's **libraries (-l)** settings, replace `libc++` with `c++`.

A secondary problem is that the Eclipse-CDT-generated link command:

```
clang++ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/ -o
C++Test src/C++Test.bc -llibc++ -lstdc++
```

is attempting to link `libstdc++` (the GCC Standard C++ library) as well as
(what is supposed to be) `libc++` (the LLVM Standard C++ library). You want to
link one or the other, not both:

You say that even if you delete `stdc++` from the project's libraries, it
is automatically added by the Eclipse build. I cannot reproduce that problem.
Perhaps you can double check it:

- Delete `stdc++` from the project's libraries and apply that change.
- Then look at the linker settings -> **All options** and see if `-lstdc++`
  appears there. It shouldn't.
- If it does, look at linker settings -> **Miscellaneous** -> **Linker flags**
  and **Other options**. Does `-lstdc++` appear there? If so, delete it.
- Otherwise, look at the linker's **Expert settings: commandline pattern**. 
  If it contains `-lstdc++`, delete it.

You say also that you have appended  the options `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` 
to the compiler **Command** setting, but this seems to be ignored. They may be 
appear to be ignored because only the link step of your project is failing, so
the compile step is not rerun when you build. However it is misguided to
add these options to the compile command:-

- `-std=c++11` is a *compile* option. You should add it to ***compiler*** ->
  **Miscellaneous** -> **Other flags**.
- `-stdlib=libc++` is a *linkage* option and, if wanted, should be
  added to ***linker*** -> **Miscellaneous** -> **Linker flags**. However it
  is superfluous to use this option if you also link with `-lc++` (and do not
  link `-lstdc++`), and `-lc++` is the more dependable option. I suggest you
  do not bother with `-stdlib=libc++`.

In view of your difficulties linking with `libc++` one should ask: Do you
really need to? The fact that you are building with clang does not oblige you 
to link `libc++`. Clang will quite happily link `libstdc++`.

Comment: Thanks,almost words now.But I do removed "stdc++" from libraries,and the linker's all options is:-L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.1 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/.

Comment: And after removing "stdc++" ,apply to close settings panel,then open settings immediatetly,"stdc++" will be added by eclipse automatically,and there is nothing in settings -> Miscellaneous -> Linker flags and Other options

Comment: See updated answer and check the linker's *Expert settings*. Does that help?

Comment: No,it will be added again and again,and by the way,I can't find "All options" and "Expert settings" in cdt 8.6